# Spark's serialization

Tags: java, serialization, apache-spark

I have a own .jar and want this .jar to be deployed into Spark. I got it but now I have problems with some new code in which "NumberFormat" and "Locale" Java clasess are used as global variables:

```
private NumberFormat machineLocale
private Locale locale
```

If I include this new code and try to deploy in Spark I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 9, sparkslave4.local): java.io.IOException: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Error during Java deserialization.
```

Serialization trace:
locale (java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols)
symbols (java.text.DecimalFormat)
numberFormat

Please, can anybody give me a clue? How I have to deal with these classes?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Although this is probably too late: Did you try and register your classes with Kryo before you serialized them?